# Find the general solution $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}x \\ y \end{smallmatrix}\right]$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, generalized-eigenvector

Let $\begin{bmatrix} \dot x \\ \dot y \end{bmatrix}$$=$$\begin{bmatrix}-5 & -3 \\ 3 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix}$.

a) Find the general solution $\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix}$.

b)Find $λ$ and a basis for which the system reduces to   ̇$\dot u=λu+v$ and  $ ̇\dot v=λv$.

The eigenvalue  $λ=-2$ gives us the eigenvector  $\begin{bmatrix}-1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and generalized eigenvector $\begin{bmatrix}1/3 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

For part a), the general solution $\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix}=c_1 e^{-2t}\begin{bmatrix}-1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}+c_2e^{-2t}\Bigg(t\begin{bmatrix}-1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}1/3 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\Bigg)$

I'm not sure about part b) can anyone explain it?

Comment: its jordan form I guess write the system with matrices with u and v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{bmatrix} \dot x \\ \dot y \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-5 & -3 \\ 3 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix}  \implies X'=AX$$
You have that
$$
\begin{cases}
u'=\lambda u + v \\
v'=\lambda v
\end{cases}
$$
$$
\implies \pmatrix { u \\ v}' =\begin{bmatrix} \lambda  & 1 \\ 0 & \lambda \end{bmatrix}\pmatrix {u \\ v } \implies U'=BU$$

B is just the Jordan matrix. Try to evaluate it  now 
$$J=H^{-1}AH$$
Where H is the matrix with eigenvectors
$$H=\pmatrix {-1 & 1/3 \\1 &0}$$

Comment: Sorry, I'm am confused about how this answers the question. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I mean that the Jordan matrix has eigenvalues on the diagonal and sometimes 1 or zero elsewhere ... @MANONMARS45

Comment: If you evaluate $H^{-1}AH$ you will have a diagonilzied matrix...Like B ...Just do the calculation it takes 5 minues.

Comment: Does the diagonal matrix H give you the vectors that form the basis?

Comment: H is not diagonal thats J or B that is diagonal as it's the matrix of the system with u and v variables...  I got for J$$J=\pmatrix {-2 &1 \\0 &-2}$$  H is the matrix that changes the basis that takes from A to matrix B  @MANONMARS45  more information here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity